How to encode from image to mp4 file use GPU?
I'm trying to convert images folder to mp4 via FFmpeg AutoGen https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen.
I use the demo of FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example
It is good for me but this is use CPU to encode.This is FFmpeg.AutoGen demo:
private static unsafe void EncodeImagesToH264()
    {
        var frameFiles = Directory.GetFiles("./frames", "frame.*.jpg").OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
        using var fistFrameImage = ReadFrame(frameFiles.First());

        var outputFileName = "frames/out.h264";
        var fps = 25;
        var sourceSize = new Size(fistFrameImage.Width, fistFrameImage.Height);
        var sourcePixelFormat = AVPixelFormat.@AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA;
        var destinationSize = sourceSize;
        var destinationPixelFormat = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
        using var vfc = new VideoFrameConverter(sourceSize, sourcePixelFormat, destinationSize, destinationPixelFormat);

        using var fs = File.Open(outputFileName, FileMode.Create);

        using var vse = new H264VideoStreamEncoder(fs, fps, destinationSize);

        var frameNumber = 0;

        foreach (var frameFile in frameFiles)
        {
            using var bitmap = ReadFrame(frameFile);
            var bitmapData = bitmap.Bytes;
            fixed (byte* pBitmapData = bitmapData)
            {
                var data = new byte_ptr8 { [0] = pBitmapData };
                var linesize = new int8 { [0] = bitmapData.Length / sourceSize.Height };
                var frame = new AVFrame
                {
                    data = data,
                    linesize = linesize,
                    height = sourceSize.Height
                };
                var convertedFrame = vfc.Convert(frame);
                convertedFrame.pts = frameNumber * fps;
                vse.Encode(convertedFrame);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"frame: {frameNumber}");
            frameNumber++;
        }

        vse.Drain();
    }

I want get a demo use GPU to encode. How can i do this?

Can anyone assist me?
